# Debezium, Kafka connect: is there a way to send only payload and not schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have an outbox postgresql table and debezium connector in kafka connect that creates kafka messages based on the added rows to the table.

The problem I am facing is with the message format. This is the created message value:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "optional": true,
    "name": "io.debezium.data.Json",
    "version": 1
  },
  "payload": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
}
```

But (because of consumer) I need the message to contain only the payload, like this:

```
{
  "\"foo\": \"bar\""
}
```

This is part of my kafka connector configuration:

```
"transforms": "outbox",
"transforms.outbox.type": "io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter",
"transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement": "${routedByValue}",
"transforms.outbox.route.by.field": "aggregate_type",
"transforms.outbox.table.field.event.payload.id": "aggregate_id",
"transforms.outbox.table.fields.additional.placement": "payload_type:header:__TypeId__"
```

Is there any way to achieve this without creating custom transformer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` with `schemas.enable=true` for your value converter. When you do this it embeds the schema alongside the payload in the message.

If you set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false` you should get just the payload in your message.

Ref: [Kafka Connect: Converters and Serialization Explained — JSON and Schemas](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas)

Comment: thank you, this does the job for JsonConverter, for my consumer case I actually had to change value converter to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` but this answer and article led me to the solution